# Fatal error: Cannot call constructor in C:\wamp\www\starter\***.php on line 8

Tags: php, oop, constructor

Hello I'm trying to learn PHP OOP and I'm getting this error I don't under stand why?

Cannot call constructor in Skipper->__construct( )

```
<?

    $user1 = new Skipper('Steven', 'Smith', 'steve@website.com.au', 'Yes');
    echo '<p>First Name: ' . $user1->getFirstName() .'</p>';
    echo '<p>Last Name: ' . $user1->getLastName() .'</p>';
    echo '<p>Email: ' . $user1->getEmail() .'</p>';
    echo '<p>Skipper: ' . $user1->getSkipper() .'</p>';
?>


<?php

    class User
    {
    protected $_first_name;
    protected $_last_name;
    protected $_email;

       public function getFirstName()
       {
        return $this->_first_name;
        }

        public function getLastName()
       {
        return $this->_last_name;
        }

        public function getEmail()
       {
        return $this->_email;
        }       
    };

?>


<?php

    class Skipper extends User
    {
    protected $_skipper;

        public function __construct($first_name, $last_name, $email, $skipper) 
       {
        parent::__construct($first_name, $last_name, $email);
        $this->_skipper = $Skipper;
        }

        final public function getSkipper()
        {
        return $this->_skipper;
        }
    }

?>
```

Comment: You should reformat the code and give us the Skipper class full code

Comment: Please format your code, there is no way to understand what's going on without the source code of your class.

Comment: Don't call the parent constructor if it doesn't exist. PHP classes don't have default constructors. A class has a constructor if and only if one is defined. More code would be helpful.

Comment: In `Skipper` class constructor you are calling parent constructor i.e. `User` class constructor, which doesn't exists ..

Comment: @Syed Qarib Exactly, Like i already said.

Comment: @tastro: Simpler version :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create a constructor in the parent class `User` or don't call the constructor in the `Skipper` class.

In your case, i think what you want is to add this constructor into your `User` class:

```
public function __construct($first_name, $last_name, $email) 
{
    $this->_first_name = $first_name;
    $this->_last_name = $last_name;
    $this->_email = $email;
}
```

After this small "fix" the error shouldn't show up anymore.